# Attribute scope missing in demo store

Tags: product-attribute, scope, magento2.4

I have put together a demo store and added a couple of store views to it.

I went to change the scope of the price attribute to 'website' from 'global' and I cannot find the scope option in the backend.

My store is 2.4 with demo data, very little changed apart from that.

I have never seen the attribute scope missing before, it shows in the admin grid but not when you edit an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The price attribute scope is changed in Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Price -> Price scope